# Creating a virtual column on SELECT and populating it in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database for an Animal Shelter. I want to create a view to show income/outcome created from records in Sponsorship, Donation tables etc.

So I need to SELECT all the donation rows and include them in my view. I also want to create a virtual row and populate this with 'Donation' to show that all these rows are donations, and the same with Sponsorship etc.

Is there are way of doing this in MySQL?

Comment: Can you show the structure of your tables?

Comment: @Marjeta I just want to know how to do this in general. Anyway, I found the answer so have answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, 'value_to_populate' AS 'virtual_column'
FROM table
```